# Difference between Dimension, Attribute and Feature in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

This is two dimensional: [[2,2]]  but it also has 2 features/attributes doesn't it. I am confused on what the difference between a dimension, attribute and feature is.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I have to dissagree with @Atilla answer

- **Dimension** usually refers to the **number** of attributes, although it can also be used in form of "second dimension of the data vector is person age", but it is rather rare - in most cases dimension is "number of attributes"
- **Attribute** is one particular "type of data" in your points, so each observation/datapoint (like personal record) contains many different attributes (like person weight, height, age, etc.)
- **Feature** may have multiple meanings depending on context:

  - It sometimes refers to attribute
  - It sometimes refers to the internal representation of the data generated by particular learning model, for example - neural networks extract **features** which are combinations of the attributes or other features
  - It sometimes refers to the hypothethical representation of the data induced by the kernel method (in Kernel PCA, Kernel k-means, SVM)

In general you have some objects X, which you describe using some *attributes* (which is the first step of **feature extraction**, and so these attributes are also sometimes refered as features), which creates a representation of given *dimension* (number of attributes, extracted features). Then you train some model, which often creates some kind of abstraction (sometimes even multi-level), and each of such abstractions generate new *features* (extracts features from features) which are more complex objects then the ones on the lower "level".

```
 X  --->   repr(X)   --->   f1(repr(X)) --->   ....  --->   fn(repr(X))
data      attributes         1st level                      nth level
        (0th features)       features                       features

      |repr(X)|=dimension
```

f's are often recurrent, so `f2(repr(X))` is actually some `f2'(f1(repr(X))`

Comment: A bit more formally:
http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VCd67cGB_rAC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=semisupervised+learning+for+computational+linguistics&source=bl&ots=Up6tBc-F38&sig=_8r_GZbP_FOcZKyDDqR07H7OjSk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dM8OVMfIIoTX7AbQvICQCQ&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=semisupervised%20learning%20for%20computational%20linguistics&f=false

Pages: 14 and 15.

Comment: so feature engineering is first step for all the ML methods ?(supervised and unsupervised

Comment: this answer is not mentioning feature **engineering**

Comment: Note that in the context of neural networks the term "intermediate features" is sometimes used to contrast with "features" (attributes) provided for training

Comment: So just to confirm, an attribute can be be feature but it is not necessary that feature can always be attribute. And dimension is just cardinality of set of attributes.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same things. Attribute, dimension and feature. According to writer's background or domain they are used interchangeably.

For example if you are talking about mathematical aspects , you can say this is high dimension problem.

Comment: One exception to this is kernel methods, where feature space denotes the nonlinearly transformed space in which the method implicitly works. Unfortunately, even there the terms are mangled together which is quite confusing for beginners.